# fgetcsv() works on localhost but gives an error when it is on a server

Tags: php, csv, fgetcsv

I'm opening a csv file from a url using this code:

```
$data=fopen('http://url.ro/file','r');
$x = 0;

while (($line = fgetcsv($data)) !== FALSE) {
    print_r($line);
    $x++;
    if($x >= 5){
        exit('exit');
    }
}
```

This works just fine on localhost but when i move it to a server i get this error:

```
PHP Warning:  fgetcsv() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
```

P.S: i'm getting the file content trough from a url(if i access that url directly it just downloads the csv file)

Comment: It probably has [`allow_url_fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/features.remote-files.php) disabled...

Comment: Hey @msg, can you help me to check that? :-s

Comment: `echo ini_get('allow_url_fopen');`

Comment: @msg, the result is `1`

Comment: Or look at the output from a `<?php phpinfo();?>` if they allow you to run `phpinfo()`

Comment: fopen is failing, it might be for permissions. You want to check that $data is not FALSE before you do anything with it. 

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

There should be some what error is with fopen to in the log files at least.

(Also you might want to make sure the server and your local machine is on the same version of php)